# NSTextView hangs while typing

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextview

I'm experiencing hangs while typing on an NSTextView. The NSTextView is on a window that I run modally.

`[NSApp runModalForWindow:[self window]];`

I'm not really sure how, but I think it has something to do with the scrollbars. When I click the "enter key" until it starts scrolling down, it always hangs.

Can you please help me how to debug this?
Regards,
Jose.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the NSTextView on InterfaceBuilder and added again and it stopped hanging... Too bad I didn't found out why...